# Performance issues on IE 11

Tags: angular

I am having issues with performance on IE 11. I have *ngFor on 50 elements. Each of those elements have some values, that I use in components (which makes it 50  additional components). Each of those elements is an object, which has its own methods. When I have 5-10 elements, everything works great. However, if I add more elements, everything slows down, until the point when IE is not responding.

I am including core.js.

Is there anything I can do about it? I am using BETA 17.

Here is my profiler (IE):

[image]

I've managed to do some more testing, and it seems that when I have 3x[routerLink] with parameters hooked up, it slows down. Also, template with ngFor is slowing the application down. I will keep my findings updated here.

**LATEST UPDATE**

It seems that the biggest performance issue blockers here are the routerLinks and ngFor directive with template.

Comment: Are you doing any computations on instantiation?

Comment: I use moment.js for 4 properties on each of obejct. I guess thats not that bad...